# Отправка запросов

Tags: php, symfony3

Хочу сделать страничку для логина. Использую symphony 3.3 и php 7.2 Логика такая:
 - пользователь вводит логин и пароль, отправляет на мой сервер
 - сервер оборачивает в Json логин и пароль, добавляет к запросу заголовок с ключом(для доступа к rest), отправляю запрос на внешний сервер с rest api
- обрабатываю ответ внешнего сервера
Подскажите как проще сделать. С помощью чего можно сформировать запрос к внешнему серверу с rest api?

Comment: Неясна структура приложения. Что за внешний сервер?

Answer (score 1):

Пока что лучшее, что можно сказать без кода - используйте любую библиотеку HTTP-клиент.

Например, Guzzle.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://authserver.ru']);
$response = $client->request(
     'POST',
     '/auth', [
     'json' => [
        'login' => 'root', 
        'password' => '123'], 
     'headers' => [
        'User-Agent' => 'testing/1.0',
        'Accept'     => 'application/json',
        'X-Foo'      => ['Bar', 'Baz']
]]);
```

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html